# SSLdump can't decrypt pcap trace

Tags: ssl, encryption, https, pcap, packet-capture

I'm trying to decrypt my tls pcap trace using ssldump and it doesn't work, but I'm able to do it in wireshark, providing correct keys and certificates (so I supposed they don't have any problem).

I'm asking if someone has a tested ssl trace to share togheter with the related certificates/keys, so I can understand if the problem is a ssldump bug, or just my fault. I was looking on the internet but I can't find anything useful...

I also installed the patch #8 from http://sourceforge.net/p/ssldump/patches/

I work on CentOS 6, OpenSSL version 1.0.1j

Thanks

### Update

I download from [wireshark sample captures wiki](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures#SSL_with_decryption_keys) the following trace+key

> **SSL with decryption keys**
>   File: snakeoil2_070531.tgz
>   Description: Example of SSL encrypted HTTPS traffic and the key to decrypt it. (example taken from the dev mailinglist)

and I'm able to see all the decrypted HTTP data traffic via wireshark.

Again, with SSldump I'm not able to decrypt the application data traffic. My output is the following:

```
$ ssldump -r snakeoil2.cap -k snakeoil2.key -d
New TCP connection #1: localhost(38713) <-> localhost(443)
1 1  0.0001 (0.0001)  C>S SSLv2 compatible client hello
  Version 3.0
  cipher suites
  SSL2_CK_RC4
  SSL2_CK_RC2
  SSL2_CK_3DES
  SSL2_CK_DES
  SSL2_CK_RC4_EXPORT40
  SSL2_CK_RC2_EXPORT40
  SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
  SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
  SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
  SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
  SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
  SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
  SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  Unknown value 0xfeff
  SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
  SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
  Unknown value 0xfefe
  SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
  SSL_RSA_EXPORT1024_WITH_RC4_56_SHA
  SSL_RSA_EXPORT1024_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
  SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
  SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC2_CBC_40_MD5
1 2  0.0021 (0.0020)  S>C  Handshake
      ServerHello
        Version 3.0
        session_id[32]=
          a0 fb 60 86 3d 1e 76 f3 30 fe 0b 01 fd 1a 01 ed
          95 f6 7b 8e c0 d4 27 bf f0 6e c7 56 b1 47 ce 98
        cipherSuite         SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        compressionMethod                   NULL
1 3  0.0021 (0.0000)  S>C  Handshake
      Certificate
1 4  0.0021 (0.0000)  S>C  Handshake
      ServerHelloDone
1 5  2.8089 (2.8067)  C>S  Handshake
      ClientKeyExchange
1 6  2.8089 (0.0000)  C>S  ChangeCipherSpec
1 7  2.8089 (0.0000)  C>S  Handshake
1 8  2.8227 (0.0138)  S>C  ChangeCipherSpec
1 9  2.8227 (0.0000)  S>C  Handshake
1 10 2.8330 (0.0103)  C>S  application_data
1 11 2.9384 (0.1054)  S>C  Handshake
1 12 2.9387 (0.0002)  C>S  Handshake
1 13 2.9389 (0.0002)  S>C  Handshake
1 14 2.9389 (0.0000)  S>C  Handshake
1 15 2.9389 (0.0000)  S>C  Handshake
1 16 2.9400 (0.0010)  C>S  Handshake
1 17 2.9400 (0.0000)  C>S  ChangeCipherSpec
1 18 2.9400 (0.0000)  C>S  Handshake
1 19 2.9434 (0.0033)  S>C  ChangeCipherSpec
1 20 2.9434 (0.0000)  S>C  Handshake
1 21 2.9448 (0.0014)  S>C  application_data
1 22 2.9448 (0.0000)  S>C  application_data
1 23 2.9644 (0.0195)  C>S  application_data
New TCP connection #2: localhost(38714) <-> localhost(443)
2 1  0.0002 (0.0002)  C>S  Handshake
      ClientHello
        Version 3.0
        resume [32]=
          a3 ca ad 46 95 5d 64 bb 33 ec b5 12 91 21 a3 50
          d2 c0 c5 f6 67 c3 cc 9e c0 4a 71 1b 92 dc 58 55
        cipher suites
        SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
        SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
        SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        Unknown value 0xfeff
        SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
        SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
        Unknown value 0xfefe
        SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
        SSL_RSA_EXPORT1024_WITH_RC4_56_SHA
        SSL_RSA_EXPORT1024_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
        SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
        SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC2_CBC_40_MD5
        compression methods
                  NULL
2 2  0.0277 (0.0274)  S>C  Handshake
      ServerHello
        Version 3.0
        session_id[32]=
          a3 ca ad 46 95 5d 64 bb 33 ec b5 12 91 21 a3 50
          d2 c0 c5 f6 67 c3 cc 9e c0 4a 71 1b 92 dc 58 55
        cipherSuite         SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        compressionMethod                   NULL
2 3  0.0277 (0.0000)  S>C  ChangeCipherSpec
2 4  0.0277 (0.0000)  S>C  Handshake
2 5  0.0282 (0.0005)  C>S  ChangeCipherSpec
2 6  0.0282 (0.0000)  C>S  Handshake
2 7  0.0282 (0.0000)  C>S  application_data
2 8  0.0289 (0.0006)  S>C  application_data
2 9  0.0289 (0.0000)  S>C  application_data
2 10 0.0292 (0.0003)  C>S  application_data
2 11 0.0296 (0.0003)  S>C  application_data
2 12 0.0296 (0.0000)  S>C  application_data
1 24 3.5016 (0.5372)  S>C  application_data
1 25 3.5016 (0.0000)  S>C  application_data
2 13 0.5424 (0.5128)  C>S  application_data
2 14 0.5429 (0.0005)  S>C  application_data
2 15 0.5429 (0.0000)  S>C  application_data
1 26 6.0378 (2.5362)  C>S  application_data
1 27 6.0411 (0.0033)  S>C  application_data
1 28 6.0411 (0.0000)  S>C  application_data
2 16 3.1243 (2.5814)  C>S  application_data
2 17 3.1455 (0.0212)  S>C  application_data
2 18 3.1455 (0.0000)  S>C  application_data
1 29 9.2325 (3.1914)  C>S  application_data
1 30 9.2359 (0.0033)  S>C  application_data
1 31 9.2359 (0.0000)  S>C  application_data
1 32 9.3185 (0.0826)  C>S  application_data
2 19 6.3589 (3.2133)  C>S  application_data
1 33 9.3276 (0.0090)  S>C  application_data
1 34 9.3276 (0.0000)  S>C  application_data
2 20 6.3632 (0.0043)  S>C  application_data
2 21 6.3632 (0.0000)  S>C  application_data
1 35 12.3565 (3.0289)  C>S  application_data
1 36 12.3682 (0.0116)  S>C  application_data
1 37 12.3682 (0.0000)  S>C  application_data
```

Any idea of what error/wrong configuration can prevent me from decrypting?

Comment: Hi, have to find a way for this one ?. Since, in my end to have sample issue